# Open Minitab file in R

Tags: r, minitab

I am currently taking a course that requires Minitab which appears to be unavailable for Linux systems. After doing some searching, I was read that RStudio can run Minitab files and to [import it using the following steps](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/foreign/html/read.mtp.html):

```
library(foreign)
myMTPData <- read.mtp("orientationdata.mpjx")
```

This leads me to the following error:

```
Error in read.mtp("orientationdata.mpjx") : 
  file 'orientationdata.mpjx' is not in Minitab Portable Worksheet format
```

Since the file is provided and I have never used Minitab before, I am not sure as to what format the file is in (.mpjx) so I can do further research on how to import it into RStudio.

Is there any way to determine this or is there any way to import .mpjx files that are not in a Minitab Portable Worksheet?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MTP file are a depreciated function of minitab. 
MPJ are for project file, recording more than the data.

The best way to proceed is to save the data into a csv file on Minitab (use a trial version if needed) and to read this file in R.

Regards